# Compare 2 arrays remove the duplicates that appear in both in php

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have two arrays, I want to remove the duplicate(the values that appear in both) And remain with values that are not in Array A. For example I have array Master_arr and Log_arr. I want to remove the duplicates that appear in both and add in master_arr values that dont exist from log_arr. Master_arr contains CAT,DOG,RABBIT and Log_arr contains CAT,DOG,RABBIT,CAR,PHONE.
I want to add CAR and PHONE to Master_arr.

```
$master_arr = array(CAT,DOG,RABBIT);
$log_arr = array(CAT,CAR,RABBIT,DOG,PHONE);
$unique=array_unique( array_merge($master_arr, $log_arr) );
print_r($unique);
```

Comment: Your code seems to work; what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
$master_arr = array(CAT,DOG,RABBIT);
$log_arr = array(CAT,CAR,RABBIT,DOG,PHONE);
$unique=array_unique( array_merge($master_arr, $log_arr) );
$master_arr=array_diff($unique, $master_arr);
print_r($master_arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, it works but in my case I have two text files with the values in the arrays I open the file add the values in the array but for some reason it seems to be getting the unique based on the array key.
     `$master_arr = array('CAT','DOG','RABBIT');`
      `$log_arr = array('CAT','RABBIT','CAR','DOG','PHONE');`

I keep getting RABBIT, CAR and PHONE

Comment: how are you adding data to array after fetching from file ?

Comment: This is how am adding the values in the array. `$master_arr = array();$master_file="CompareA.txt";
$file = fopen($master_file, "r");

while (!feof($file)) {
   $master_arr[] = fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);`

Comment: use `trim(fgets($file));` instead while getting contents from file

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want

```
$unique = array_diff(array_merge($master_arr, $log_arr), $master_arr);
```